# SQL query to calculate average and insert into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a song archive database and I'm stuck on some queries.  I would like to -

- Calculate the rating of each user by their average `Comments` value of `score` and inserting the rating into `Users`
- Calculating how much Purchases each user has
- Calculate the average `score` of a `Song` from the `Comments` table
- Calculating how many `credits` each user has spent on their purchases

Below you can find my tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    username   NVARCHAR( 30 )   NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
    pass       NVARCHAR( 16 ),
    email      NVARCHAR( 50 ),
    city       NVARCHAR( 10 ),
    credits    INT,
    rating     INT
)

CREATE TABLE Songs
(
    song_id       INT              NOT NULL   IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )   PRIMARY KEY,
    song_name     NVARCHAR( 30 ),
    username      NVARCHAR( 30 ),
    genre         INT,
    price         INT,
    song_length   INT,
    listens       INT
)

CREATE TABLE Genres
(
    genre_id     INT              NOT NULL   IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )   PRIMARY KEY,
    genre_name   NVARCHAR( 16 )
)


CREATE TABLE Purchases
(
    purchase_id      INT              NOT NULL   IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )   PRIMARY KEY,
    song_id          INT,
    username         NVARCHAR( 30 )
    date_purchased   DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE Comments
(
    comment_id   INT   NOT NULL   IDENTITY ( 1, 1 )   PRIMARY KEY,
    username     NVARCHAR( 30 ),
    song_id      INT,
    text         NVARCHAR( 30 ),
    score        INT
)
```

Comment: This is to broad,please try reducing the scope of the question.Say for example ,you have asked this `Calculating the rating of each user by its average comment score`..try calculating average score and post the question if you have any difficulties

Comment: @TheGameiswar I know it is but its kinda urgent and I'm too rusty, I have another queries I should write but I need those to get the hang of it, it will help me a lot

Comment: I have edited your Question to make the presentation and layout style more *consistent* and reduced the excessive usage of spaces / tabs.  I have improved the English usage slightly.  Please edit the second point to clarify if you are asking for how *many* purchases they have made (the count of Purchases), the total value of their Purchases or the average value of their Purchases.  If you have any code that you have been trying, then please add that (with the error messages it produces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered some of your questions. In addition to the respective queries I arranged them as common table expressions, which I think could be a  convenient way to use them...

Calculating how much credits each user has spent on his purchases, might require to know your logic about how users invest their credits.

```
    WITH CTE_PurchasesByUser AS
    (
        SELECT p.username as username,  count(*) as NrOfPurchases
        FROM Purchases p
        GROUP BY p.username
    ),
    CTE_AverageScoreBySong AS
    (
        SELECT c.song_id as song_id, (sum(c.score)/count(c.score)) as AverageScore
        FROM Comments c
        GROUP BY c.song_id
    ),
    CTE_AverageScoreByUser AS
    (
        SELECT u.username as username, (sum(c.score)/count(c.score)) as AverageScore
        FROM Users u
        INNER JOIN Comments c ON u.username = c.username
        GROUP BY u.username
    )
    SELECT u.*, ISNULL(bbu.NrOfPurchases,0), asu.AverageScore 
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN CTE_PurchasesByUser bbu ON u.username = bbu.username
    LEFT JOIN CTE_AverageScoreByUser asu ON u.username = asu.username
```

This SQL ran with your tables, yet I didn't test it with data rows...

Comment: Thank you so much, I think i got the idea, do you have any good website to help me with procedures maybe?